# VS 2017 RC missing Windows 10 Mobile Emulator

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I installed Visual Studio 2017 RC, and in general I'm really impressed! One problem, however, is that I can't figure out the proper method of installing the Windows 10 Mobile Emulator. I have installed the Windows 10 SDK as well as the Emulator itself. My Programs and Features clearly shows these two items are installed:

. Windows 10 for Mobile Image - 10.0.14393.0
. Windows Software Development Kit - Windows 10.0.14393.33

I also have properly selected the Cordova tools during the installation of VS 2017 RC. I can create a new JavaScript project using Cordova and it looks to be correct in the Solution Explorer.

But when I launch Visual Studio 2017 RC and then inspect the Solution Platforms dropdown, it only has these options:

Android
iOS
Windows-ARM
Windows-x64
Windows-x86
Configuration Manager...

I do not see any option for Windows 10 Mobile.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind.... Somehow I installed more stuff and then found what I am looking for by selecting Windows-X86, and then there are options for Mobile Emulator 10.0.14393.0 in various memory and screen configurations. Just keep clicking things until it works, I suppose... Seriously, probably my own fault. Moving on!